# R ggplot geom_point overlay from 2 data frames, differentiated by color, subset by id

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, subset

I have two data frames with identical rows and columns, `DataMaster` and `IMPSAVG`, for which I'm trying to create a series of combined overlaid 2d scatterplots (subset by country "ids" and variable columns) with observations from the two data sets differentiated by color in ggplot. The code below does not work, but gives a sense of what I'm aiming for (`acctm` is the variable  and `ARG` is the country in this example).

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=DataMaster, aes(x="Year", y="acctm"), subset = .(Country %in% c("ARG")), shape=21, color= "red") +
  geom_point(data=IMPSAVG, aes(x="Year", y="acctm"), subset = .(Country %in% c("ARG")), shape=21, color= "blue")
```

While just getting the above to work would be much appreciated, a loop to create separate plots of this variable for all unique country ids in the column `Country` found in both datasets (also specified by the vector `CountryList$Country`) would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Without being able to run your code (don't have your data) or seeing any output, I'll guess that you could just row-bind the two datasets together with a column showing which dataset is comes from, then assign that to color. That would better fit the way ggplot is designed to work. You also don't need strings around column names there, and I'm not sure where the `subset` argument comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reproducible example of your dataset, it is hard ot be sure of what you ar elooking for.

However, using these fake datasets:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Country = c("A","A","A","B","B"),
                  Year = 2010:2014,
                  Value = sample(1:100,5))
df2 <- data.frame(Country = c("A","A","A","B","B"),
                  Year = 2010:2014,
                  Value = sample(1:100,5))
```

**1) Plotting without joining datasets (not the most appropriate)**

You don't have to absolutely assemble your dataframes to plot them, however it will make things a little bit harder (especially if you want to customize several parameters).
Here you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = "blue"), shape = 21)+
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = "red"), shape = 21, show.legend = TRUE)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","red"), labels = c("df1","df2"), name = "")
```

[image]

**2) Assembling both dataframes (best way to do it)**

However, it will be much easier if you assemble your both dataframes (`ggplot2` is designed to work with dataframes in a longer format).

So, here, you can do:

```r
df1$Dataset = "DF1"
df2$Dataset = "DF2"
DF <- rbind(df1,df2)

   Country Year Value Dataset
1        A 2010    66     DF1
2        A 2011    64     DF1
3        A 2012    40     DF1
4        B 2013    58     DF1
5        B 2014    20     DF1
6        A 2010    78     DF2
7        A 2011    25     DF2
8        A 2012    71     DF2
9        B 2013    40     DF2
10       B 2014    61     DF2
```

Now, you can simply plot it like this which is much more concise:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = Dataset))+
  geom_point(shape = 21)
```

[image]

**3) Subsetting dataframe**

To plot only a subset of your dataframes, starting with the assembled dataframe `DF`, you can simply do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(DF, Country =="A"), aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = Dataset))+
  geom_point(shape = 21)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new dataframe, which combines those two dataframes and subsets the countries that you are interested in. You can use `rbind` for combining the two, and also you should add a column for samples indicating which dataframe they are coming from, so that you can use it later in `aes(..., color = new_column)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto dc37's excellent write up, here is the trick to have one dataframe print on top of the other

```
ggplot(subset(DF, Country =="A"), aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = Dataset)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, na.rm = T) +
  geom_point(data = subset(DF, Dataset == DF1 & Country == "A"),
     aes(x = Year, y = compi, color = E), shape = 21, na.rm = T)
```

where "DF1" is the dataframe you want plotted on top.